# Highchart gap like highstock

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to make a lot of several different types of graphs. I want to break the the line when there is a data gap. I am using sensor generated data so adding null is not an option. Because the site uses several different graph types I want to stick with Highcharts for all the graphs, but am looking for the gapsize feature that is available in Highstock.

It there a way to get the gapsize or similar feature to work with Highchart NOT Highstock?

Thanks

Comment: How about null points inside a series ?

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to already know, inserting `null` will accomplish this. Why is it not an option? Even if you don't control the server returning the data, you can still manipulate it before passing it to Highcharts.

Another option is you could create another series in the chart, but this is more complex than inserting `null`. Either option requires the data to be manually manipulated.

If you still think inserting null is not an option, post some code and also detail how you will know where the break should happen.